# Sygic SDK or HERE SDK for Navigation App

Tags: maps, sdk, navigation

Sygic Maps SDK vs HERE SDK for Mobile Development

We are interested in developing a highly functional navigation app for Android and iOS. While looking into SDKs, we came across Sygic and HERE. Both look promising, but have a few queries regarding the functionality and support. Our main requirements include

1. TTS for Navigation in multiple Languages
2. Offline Region wise Maps
3. Vehicle Customized Configuration (eg Waight, Height, Width, ADR Tunnel Codes specially for trucks)?
4. Day/Night Modes
5. Auto Zoom
6. Lane Assist
7. Categorized POIs
8. Traffic Incidents
9. Different Measurement Units (kmph, mph, fph)
10. Coorinates (Compass with multiple units e.g. degree, minutes)
11. Route Planning (e.g. Route with Tolls, without tolls, local route vs highway, fastest, most economical),

Both of there SDKs provide almost all of the above functionality, as per their websites.

Which one is better in terms of support and documentation and which one better suits our requirements?